# Switching database issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just switched my app from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL, and when I try to load page on `http://localhost:3000/` or run rake db:migrate, I get:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Database YAML:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: store_delevopment
  pool: 5
```

(now I'm statring server in development mode using default Rails server.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the methods on these entries to "trust" in your PostgreSQL `data/pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: I don't have such file...This folder is empty. Also while installing there was some non-fatal errors rendered

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: It was latest one, but now I set up 9.0, installed, it works pretty well and server 5433 is started, but still can't create DB

Comment: thank you for help, finally, there was several issues in my configuration of database.yaml, finally step-by-step debugged

Comment: You got it running? Or you still having problems creating the DB?

Comment: I created a DB and running app without any troubles now)